# Пропали элементы в toolbox

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

В `VS15` перестали отображаться элементы в `toolbox`. Раньше можно было оттуда радиобаттоны тырить, а сейчас пишет:

> there are no usable controls in this group. Drag an item onto this text to add it to the toolbox.

Перепробовал всё, что нагуглил: перезапускал идю, делал ресет для тулбокса, делал `choose items`, `show all`, перезагружал комп, удалял кэши в `appdata`, даже полностью переставил студию (полдня грузил!!!) - ничего не помогло.

Что делать? Help!!!